# Nswag/Swashbuckle ASP net core openApi document with dynamic request branch logic

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, nswag

If you have controller which doesn't include mapped branch then how to support that in openAPI document generated by Nswag or Swashbuckle?

I have tried reverse proxy thing but it is not working.

Consider C# ASP.NET Core 2.2 for C# code.
For example, I have two APIController with following routes:
`Controller A: [Route("Clients")]`
`Controller B: [Route("Students")]`

Now I have request branching in `startup.cs` in `Configure` method where I map each app to different route using something like this

```
app.Map("/business", businessApp =>
{
   businessApp.UseMvc();
});

app.Map("/school", schoolApp =>
{
   schoolApp.UseMvc();
});

app.UseSwaggerAPI(_swaggerConfiguration);
```

Now if you want to hit controller A then request will be like this `http://localhost/business/Clients` and `http://localhost/school/students`

Now problem here is that in openAPI swagger document `swagger.json` path points to only controller route, so it returns `404 Not Found` while making request. How to fix this document so in swagger document path will be actual path after request branches.

I expect to work routes with branches for swagger/openAPI

Comment: In Swashbuckle look into iDocumentFilters

Comment: @RicoSuter any ideas about NSwag?

Comment: IDocumentProcessor or IOperationProcessor,

Comment: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/Document-Processors-and-Operation-Processors